# Introducing errors when refactoring within <Route /> in React front end

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

Good evening,

I am rather new to `React` and am having an issue with rending react components after refactoring.  I am sure that my problem is a simple syntax error but I am too much of a neophyte to figure it out on my own.

Here is the my render method.  When coded as follows everything is fine (forgive the oddities, it's still largely test code to be replaced when it's working how I want it to):

```
    let people = null;

    if (this.state.passersby) {
        people = (
            <Passersby
                name={this.state.passersby.name}
                activity={this.state.passersby.activity}
                key={this.state.passersby.id}
                passersby={this.state.passersby}
                clicked={this.deleteThisJeff}
            />
        )
    }

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" render={() => {
                    return (<div>
                        <h1>Jeffs?</h1>
                        <button onClick={this.startJeff}>Start the Jeffing</button>
                        <button onClick={this.postInterval}>Interval Test</button>
                        <button onClick={this.stopIt}>NO MORE JEFFS</button>
                        <Suspense fallback={<div>Jeff Could Be Anywhere...</div>}>
                            {people}
                        </Suspense>
                        <div ref={(el) => { this.bottomElement = el }} />
                    </div>)}
                } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

but when refactored as follows:

```
    let playing = (
        <div>
            <h1>Jeffs?</h1>
            <button onClick={this.startJeff}>Start the Jeffing</button>
            <button onClick={this.postInterval}>Interval Test</button>
            <button onClick={this.stopIt}>NO MORE JEFFS</button>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Jeff Could Be Anywhere...</div>}>
                {people}
            </Suspense>
            <div ref={(el) => { this.bottomElement = el }} />
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/"
                    render={() => {
                        return { playing }
                    }
                    } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

I get the following error:

"Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {playing}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
    in Route (at Public.js:135)..."

or as follows:

```
    let playing = (
        <div>
            <h1>Jeffs?</h1>
            <button onClick={this.startJeff}>Start the Jeffing</button>
            <button onClick={this.postInterval}>Interval Test</button>
            <button onClick={this.stopIt}>NO MORE JEFFS</button>
            <Suspense fallback={<div>Jeff Could Be Anywhere...</div>}>
                {people}
            </Suspense>
            <div ref={(el) => { this.bottomElement = el }} />
        </div>
    );

    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route
                    exact
                    path="/"
                    component={playing}
                    />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
```

I get the following error:

"Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object."

What do I need to fix?  I can be content with a messy  if necessary but I appreciate any help in furthering my understanding of `JSX`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, the issue is that you don't need those curly braces in your return:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => {
        return playing 
     }
 } />
```

When you add the curly brackets around the playing variable, it's being treated as a Javascript object.

Answer (score 2):

If I could just improve on jme's answer a bit since I can't comment. You could just do:

```
<Route
    exact
    path="/"
    render={() => playing}
/>
```

It does the same thing, it's just cleaner.